# Excel formula compare a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to compare a row Table A to Table B but value have different column. I need formula for if they are match or not.

I already tried Match or IF but criteria range are applicable to one cell.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWoLt.jpg)

Comment: If you show the data clearly for the two tables that may help us.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options, here is an array example:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:C2=TRANPOSE(E2:G2)))=3,"Yes","No")
```

Confirm through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

A simple non-array version would be to just add multiple countif:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:C2,E2)+COUNTIF(A2:C2,F2)+COUNTIF(A2:C2,G2)=3,"Yes","No")
```

Or a combination with `AND`:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A2:C2,E2),COUNTIF(A2:C2,F2),COUNTIF(A2:C2,G2)),"Yes","No")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(TableB[@Header4],TableA[@],0)*MATCH(TableB[@Header5],TableA[@],0)*MATCH(TableB[@Header6],TableA[@],0))
```

Translation:

- Match cell E2 with the first row of TableA, multiplied by:
- Match cell F2 with the first row of TableA, multiplied by:
- Match cell G2 with the first row of TableA

If any of these three functions fails, the whole formula returns #N/A (that is why we need to check it by using ISNUMBER).

Hope it works for you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=IF(OR(A2=E2,A2=F2,A2,G2,B2=E2,B2=F2,B2=G2,C2=E2,C2=F2,C2=G2),"YES","NO")
```

Put it to your match column and drag it down.

Comment: Should A2,G2 be A2=G2 in "IF(OR(A2=E2,A2=F2,A2,G2,B2=E2," ??